# Joining multiple arrays in R

Tags: arrays, r

In R, arrays can be merged with abind() from the 'abind' package.

I have a 3D array, x, of dims = c(5, 5, 2)

array(1:50, dim = c(5, 5, 2))

```
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    6   11   16   21
[2,]    2    7   12   17   22
[3,]    3    8   13   18   23
[4,]    4    9   14   19   24
[5,]    5   10   15   20   25

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   26   31   36   41   46
[2,]   27   32   37   42   47
[3,]   28   33   38   43   48
[4,]   29   34   39   44   49
[5,]   30   35   40   45   50
```

I am trying to use abind() to get x in the following form, so that dims = c(10, 5, 1):

```
         [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    1    6   11   16   21
 [2,]    2    7   12   17   22
 [3,]    3    8   13   18   23
 [4,]    4    9   14   19   24
 [5,]    5   10   15   20   25
 [6,]   26   31   36   41   46
 [7,]   27   32   37   42   47
 [8,]   28   33   38   43   48
 [9,]   29   34   39   44   49
[10,]   30   35   40   45   50
```

but abind is not behaving as expected.

How can this easy be accomplished if ordering of array elements is to be maintained?

Comment: if your first array is `a <- array(rep(NA,50),dim = c(5,5,2))` you can do 
`b <- array(c(a),dim = c(10,5,1))`

Comment: It's not clear from the OP's example whether it's important to preserve the order of elements in each of the 2D slices. The above solution doesn't guarantee that.

Comment: @jdobres I have added the stipulation that preservation of array slices is needed. Thanks!

Comment: it might be useful for next readers to edit question with example data used in answers, this NA array is not very explicit

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Sure I can do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`abind` accepts an arbitrary number of separate arguments that are then "glued" together along some specified dimension. Working with a somewhat more informative example matrix:

```
a <- array(1:50, c(5,5,2))

, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    6   11   16   21
[2,]    2    7   12   17   22
[3,]    3    8   13   18   23
[4,]    4    9   14   19   24
[5,]    5   10   15   20   25

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   26   31   36   41   46
[2,]   27   32   37   42   47
[3,]   28   33   38   43   48
[4,]   29   34   39   44   49
[5,]   30   35   40   45   50
```

You could do:

```
b <- abind(a[,,1], a[,,2], along = 1)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    1    6   11   16   21
 [2,]    2    7   12   17   22
 [3,]    3    8   13   18   23
 [4,]    4    9   14   19   24
 [5,]    5   10   15   20   25
 [6,]   26   31   36   41   46
 [7,]   27   32   37   42   47
 [8,]   28   33   38   43   48
 [9,]   29   34   39   44   49
[10,]   30   35   40   45   50
```

Or for an arbitrary number of 2D slices you can skip `abind` entirely and use `apply`, though the syntax is a little less intuitive.

```
b <- apply(a, 2, '[')

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    1    6   11   16   21
 [2,]    2    7   12   17   22
 [3,]    3    8   13   18   23
 [4,]    4    9   14   19   24
 [5,]    5   10   15   20   25
 [6,]   26   31   36   41   46
 [7,]   27   32   37   42   47
 [8,]   28   33   38   43   48
 [9,]   29   34   39   44   49
[10,]   30   35   40   45   50
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x <-array(1:50, dim=c(5,5,2))
library(abind)
dim(abind(x[,,1],x[ , ,2],  along=1))
```

Here is the result

```
> dim(abind(x[ , ,1],x[ , ,2],  along=1))
[1] 10  5


> abind(x[,,1],x[ , ,2],  along=1)
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    1    6   11   16   21
 [2,]    2    7   12   17   22
 [3,]    3    8   13   18   23
 [4,]    4    9   14   19   24
 [5,]    5   10   15   20   25
 [6,]   26   31   36   41   46
 [7,]   27   32   37   42   47
 [8,]   28   33   38   43   48
 [9,]   29   34   39   44   49
[10,]   30   35   40   45   50
```